# Retrieve configuration bindings WCF

Tags: wcf-binding

I have a service that exposes multiple endpoints. One beeing wsHttp and the other Net.Tcp. Is there any way I can know which one the clients used to make the call inside the service method ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [OperationContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.operationcontext.aspx) object to retrieve the channel information

```
if (OperationContext.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttp)
{
   // Called by wsHTTP
}
else if (OperationContext.Channel.LocalAddress.Uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeNetTcp)
{
   // Called by NetTcp
}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes. If you look at the following property you should be able to tell where things came in from.

```
OperationContext.Current.EndpointDispatcher.EndpointAddress
```